# not able to display json data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, crud

I'm trying to learn AngularJs. 
So I'm working on this example where I need enter code here to display database records on html.

But all I get is

```
Name    {{Response.Name}} 
Father Name {{response.FatherName}}
Address {{Contact.Address}} 
Phone Number    {{Contact.PhoneNumber}}
```

I am not getting the values.

This is my fetchdata,js

```
    var MyApp = angular.module('FetchData', []);
    MyApp.controller('', function ($scope, RecordService) { 
         //inject $scope and RecordService.
        $scope.Contact = null;
        RecordService.GetRecord().then(function (d) {
            $scope.Contact = d.data; // Success
        }, function () {
            alert('Failed'); // Failed
        });
    });

    MyApp.factory('RecordService', function ($http) {
        var fac = {};
        //GetRecord function will call the GetStudentRecord action method.
        fac.GetRecord = function () {
            return $http.get('/StudentController/GetStudentRecord');
        }
        return fac;
    });
```

Okay this is my html

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; //SHared layout
}
<h2>How to Fetch Data From Database using AngularJs.</h2>
<div ng-controller="StudentController">

    <table class="table table-responsive caption">
        <tr>
            <td>Name </td>
            <td>{{Response.Name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Father Name </td>
            <td>{{response.FatherName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>{{Contact.Address}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone Number</td>
            <td>{{Contact.PhoneNumber}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what is not working

Comment: Please can you try to add some additional info? Like console logs

Comment: The values are not getting displayed on the cshtml index view

Comment: But are you sure that the call for the rest service gone well? @user3500179
I see a bit error on declaration of controller. 
`MyApp.controller('', function ($scope, RecordService)` have to be 
`MyApp.controller('$scope', 'RecordService', function ($scope, RecordService)` but I want be sure that rest call gone well.

Comment: Yes as I can see the response in the getStudent  method

Comment: consider to change the declaration of controller as I typed, first. @user3500179

Comment: Can you edit your question adding also html?

Comment: Yes I tried that as well

Comment: Can you add the response for the getStudentRecord API.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your code and putting a breakpoint on the following line of code to make sure that d.data exists and will be assigned to $scope.Contact:

```
$scope.Contact = d.data; // Success
```

The other thing is that **response** and **Response** don't appear to be defined.

My last suggestion is to make sure that these variables are present in the current controller. On your **div** in the html you have *ng-controller="StudentController"* written. Be sure that your variables are in that controller.